# SQL query for Checking value in an multi dimension array using WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

MY tables has entries in following format

```
ID DATA
1  {"rows":[{"unit":"10","price":"20"},{"unit":"20","price":"30"},{"unit":"30","price":"40"},{"unit":"40","price":"50"}],"table":"\n<table>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th>Unit</th>\n<th>Price</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n\n<tbody>\n\n<tr><td>10</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>20</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>40</td><td>50</td></tr>\n\n</tbody>\n\n</table>\n"}
```

I want entries where `unit = 30`.

I tried

```
 SELECT * from content Where '30' IN "(".implode(',',`data`).");
```

but that returns an error. Please Help

Comment: What's the expected output? And what MySQL version are you using.

Comment: for better results you have to write code after fetching the json data from mysql. Adding json data to a mysql column is a bad idea.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The expected output are the entries from Table Content which has unit 30 in its data Column. Mysql version is 4.7.7

Comment: You call `{"unit":"30","price":"40"}` a entity? Mysql version is 4.7.7  really? That's a stone age MySQL version without JSON parsing/searching functions i advice you to upgrade.. Or if you are with a hosting provider move to a other that atleast supports MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE data LIKE '%"unit":"30"%';
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Stackoverflow need more people like you, helping others when needed to solve the problem rather than complaining.

Comment: My pleasure.  When you have enough rep, please upvote.